# Using productbuild for mac os x app with additional tools and files

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker, productbuild

For one of my projects i used building script using packagemaker. Packagemaker allows specify all files i need install from root, so my root had following structure:

```
Applications
    My Application.app
Library
    Preferences
        MyCompanyName
            some.xml
            another.xml
tmp
    default.p12
usr
    local
        bin
            sometool
```

I.e. it had following features:

1. Some configuration files preinstalled for all users, to global Preferences (some.xml, another.xml)
2. Some command line tool being used as by main app as user in /usr/local/bin
3. Program uses certificates and there is one default certificate which will be moved to right place in postflight

How to do same with productbuild? Possible?

Answer (score 0):

The basic tool that does the packaging you want is pkgbuild, not productbuild. pkgbuild will let you specify a root directory that, upon installation, will be expanded to '/'. So, you can use that for all of what you discuss in your question (though an installer putting something in /tmp is a bit weird - I'd suggest baking the cert right into your postinstall script).